# Hibernate project reference org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and Restful.

I have sample java project( Hibernate java project) in my RAD. It's working and able to run my Hibernate query's

I have another web project (Restful sample web project), It's working able to run my sample application get and post.

I want to integrate Hibernate Java project in my Web project. My idea is I want publish my sample hibernate in Restful service. My restful get service call my hibernate module and run the query's and give result to end user.

I have given Hibernate java project as reference in web project, included all jar files as user library, added deployment assembly Hibernate project and user library. I have crated my HibernateUtlity class object trying invoke my getSession method. ITs giving strange exception.

```
Mar 11, 2015 6:11:17 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 11, 2015 6:11:17 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Mar 11, 2015 6:11:17 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.googlesvn.practice.examples.hibernate.ramaschi.sample.inheritance.curd.Account
Mar 11, 2015 6:11:18 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.googlesvn.practice.examples.hibernate.ramaschi.sample.inheritance.curd.Account on table ACCOUNT
Mar 11, 2015 6:11:18 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
    at com.googlesvn.practice.examples.hibernate.runner.HibernateUtilty.getHibernateSession(HibernateUtilty.java:17)
    at com.googlesvn.practice.dao.interfaces.impl.DaoInterfaceImpl.getAccountDetails(DaoInterfaceImpl.java:17)
    at com.googlesvn.practice.zdao.zhibernate.runner.HibernateRunner.main(HibernateRunner.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:175)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:347)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:173)
    ... 15 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.googlesvn.practice.dao.interfaces.impl.DaoInterfaceImpl.getAccountDetails(DaoInterfaceImpl.java:18)
    at com.googlesvn.practice.zdao.zhibernate.runner.HibernateRunner.main(HibernateRunner.java:14)
```

FYI:- I am not using Springs, I am using Web sphere 8 for running my Rest web project.

Can you please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are running on WebSphere 8, maybe you should consider using JPA, which is already provided there instead of Hibernate (since you are new to it anyway). It is better integrated and probably will be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I am using JPA for the mappings. in my hibernate.cfg.xml I have only 1 mapping and basic Hibernate properties. Its not even loading SessionFactory. Its throwing execution while calling buildSessionFactory() method.

Comment: So if you are planning to use JPA, then remove your hibernate jars and switch to configuration via `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` files (or annotations), which are common to JPA providers, rather than using proprietary hibernate files. Then you may use default JPA provider implemented by the server (which is openJPA in case of WAS) without using third party libraries in your application. Unless of course you are required to use Hibernate.

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner I tried your solution, It doesn't work for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630185/error-creating-bean-entitymanagerfactory-nested-hibernateexception-unable-to

Comment: @Gas, I have to use Hibernate. I was using JPA annotations.

Comment: Did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948806/hibernate-could-not-create-configuration-during-spring-initialization) it looks fairly similar. How are you packaging your HIbernate and validation library jars?

Comment: @Gas, I have tried that. It doesn't help me. I am not using Springs. I felt the above solution for Springs. I found couple of same problems which related to Spring and Hibernate integration.

Comment: The issue is probably about libraries. Add to your question what jars you have and where are they placed (ear, shared libs in WAS), you may also need to set classloader to  `Parent_last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you guys are the help. I found the solution for this problem. Issue is the my Hibernate project is not added to my Web project maven build. Once I added Hibernate project as dependency to my Web project. After successful deployment. Its working. Still I don't have any idea Why its throwing Bean Validation exception.